# zappa is packaging extra files which are available in another directory

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I have a simple flask application and I want to deploy that on AWS environment using `Zappa`.

My repository structure will be like this:

```
MyBackend
   misc
     -project1
     -project2
       .
       .
     -project n
   MyFlaskApplication
     -flask-code
     -zappa-settings.json
     -requirments.txt
```

If you see above project structure, I have two different projects,`misc` and `MyFlaskApplication`.

I went to `MyFlaskApplication` project path and performed these steps:

```
virtualenv .venv
. .venv/bin/activate

pip3 install zappa

zappa package dev -o artifact.zip
```

I want to upload this zipped (`artifact.zip`) into S3 then my `ci/cd` will take care of deployment of this zip file on Lambda.

**Issue**

When I try to package `MyFaskApplication`, `zappa` is packaging `misc` project codes as well. Because of this my zip file size increases rapidly like `400MB`.

I want to package only `my flask code` not `misc` projects.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein for editing my question.

Comment: Have you tryed using "exclude": ['psycopg', ... ]? The value is a list of libraries. I am not aware of how to exclude directories. Maybe you could move the dir misc away?!